# How do I properly redirect a dynamic URL to a static URL of my choice using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dynamic

I have a questions & answers type of thing set up, and when a visitor wants to ask a question, they must log in first.  The login is dynamic; the page is located at:

http://discuss.nationalcdp.org/questions/

There, the "ask" button points to:

https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/questions/ask

When a non logged-in visitor clicks this, they're redirected to:

```
https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/ncdp-login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F 
%2Fdiscuss.nationalcdp.org%2Fquestions%2Fask
```

I have went into my cPanel and configured redirects -- **with and without wildcards** -- to no avail.  I've tried:

```
https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/ncdp-login/ redirects to:
https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/login/
```

Lastly, and I knew this wouldn't work but tried it anyway, I set up:

```
https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/ncdp-login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F 
%2Fdiscuss.nationalcdp.org%2Fquestions%2Fask  redirects to
https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/login/
```

Should I be staying out of the cPanel and handling this with the root .htaccess file?

**This is what the cPanel is writing to my htaccess file, where basically I'm trying to get /subdomain/ncdp-login and /subdomain/register/ to redirect to the root domain:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^directory\.nationalcdp\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.directory\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^ncdp\-login$ "https\:\/\/nationalcdp\.org\/profile\/login\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^directory\.nationalcdp\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.directory\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^register\/$ "https\:\/\/nationalcdp\.org\/profile\/register\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^discuss\.nationalcdp\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.discuss\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^register\/$ "https\:\/\/nationalcdp\.org\/profile\/register\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.nationalcdp\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.forums\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^ncdp\-login$ "https\:\/\/nationalcdp\.org\/profile\/login\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.nationalcdp\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.forums\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^register\/$ "https\:\/\/nationalcdp\.org\/profile\/register\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^discuss\.nationalcdp\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.discuss\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^ncdp\-login\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/nationalcdp\.org\/profile\/login\/$1"    
[R=301,L]
```

Any guidance in how I can get this dynamically generated login URL to redirect to https://discuss.nationalcdp.org/login/ would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check what .htaccess is being written by cpanel?

Comment: Hi Anubhava.  I have edited the question to reflect what the rewrite rules are the cPanel is inducing in htaccess.  Thanks!

Comment: Surely you wouldn't want to loose the query string when redirecting an url with redirect_to to /login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule as **very first** rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^discuss\.nationalcdp\.org$
RewriteRule ^ncdp-login/?$ /profile/login/? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Do comment out (remove) all the other rules for `/ncdp-login`.

Comment: Hey, thanks Anubhava!  That was finally the solution that worked.  I appreciate you taking the time to help!